# itertools with exception windowserror

Tags: python, count, python-itertools, winreg

In this piece of code, which its run, i dont understand why raise a WindowsError. If I dont write a break sentence, at the strout is written as  infinite loop:

> member 'strerror' of 'OSError' objects  flag2

As https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count says, count() is equivalent to a for loop.

Is it possible that when itertools.count() reachs the last element, raise the error and as, I write a break sentence, it is possible get out the for loop?.

I dont know it I had been enought clear...
That's the code:

```
for i in itertools.count():
    try:
        val=winreg.EnumValue(key,i)
        print(str(val[1]))
        if (val[1]=='COM3'): #SERIAL PORT
            port=val[1] #COM PORT
    except WindowsError:
        print(WindowsError.strerror, ' flag2')
        break
```

For me the code it's fine and runs, but I just want to know if itertools raise an error because it reachs at the last element and for that I have to code a break sentence. And if it is, if there is a alternative code without erros, or maybe more elegant.

thanks

Comment: there is no *last element* with `itertools.count()`. It counts to infinity (expects a break-termination)

Comment: Also it is very unclear to me what your point\problem is. Can you rephrase your question maybe?

Comment: As Ev. says, if you remove the `break` your loop is infinite, and so `i` will keep incrementing by 1 and presumably the exception is raised every subsequent iteration, hence your infinite loop printing the error message

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thanks men. that is I thought

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes, if I print var i, it stars at 4, in my case,  and so on. thanks